# Multiple IIS Application With Same C# MVC Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm building a site for SaaS.
I'd like to distinguish sites by Domain name to use same contoller.

The reason why I want to make multiple IIS Application is, 
There are tons of `HttpContext.Current.Application` in `Application_Start()` and `OnActionExecuting()`. And It should be isolated by domains.

My questions are :

- Is there any solution for multiple IIS Application using same C# MVC controllers?
- If not, Is there other container instead of `HttpContext.Current.Application`?
- Or, Is there other solution that is more elegant, efficient, or effective?

What I tried for creating multiple IIS Application are :

- Setting same path.
- Set only `bin` directory to same path as virtual directory

However, Nothing works.
I Hope this is helpful

> Windows Server 2012 / IIS 8.5 
>   VS 2013 / C# MVC5 / .Net Framework v4.5.0

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Different websites on different domains, one .NET MVC application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104251/different-websites-on-different-domains-one-net-mvc-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any solution for multiple IIS Application using same C# MVC controllers?

Yes.

[IIS7 - How do I use the same physical path for different domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540256/iis7-how-do-i-use-the-same-physical-path-for-different-domains)

[Can I configure IIS to use the same physical path for different sites but use custom web.config](https://serverfault.com/questions/213452/can-i-configure-iis-to-use-the-same-physical-path-for-different-sites-but-use-cu)

> If not, Is there other container instead of HttpContext.Current.Application?
>
> Or, Is there other solution that is more elegant, efficient, or effective?

It is possible to have multiple domains pointed to a single web application. For more information take a look at [IIS Bindings](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/site/bindings/binding)

Comment: Thank you so much! I added new site and set same path. but I didn't add 'Application Pool'. That links were very helpful for me.